Which NextJS version for Sitecore/JSS X?
I got the question to check which version of NextJS was compatible with Sitecore 10.2 - 10.4. I managed to find information in the Compatibility table but that refers to the versions of JSS / Headless Services. But I wasn't able to match that to versions of NextJS yet. In some release notes I could find an update to a Next version - e.g. the notes of v20 mentions Next 12. I didn't find any information on newer versions however. And as some release notes do mention Next versions, I am assuming we cannot simply upgrade that and keep the JSS version.
So my question is: if my customer is asking for a specific minimal version of NextJS, how and where can I find which version of JSS I should use (and that implies the version of Sitecore as well).
The question is for a XM/XP customer - but interested in how this goes on XMCloud as well.

I haven't been able to find a compatibility table between NextJS and Sitecore JSS versions either. To answer your question, if you are looking for a minimum compatible version of NextJS for each version of Sitecore JSS, I recommend looking at the version of the next npm package in the package.json file of the sitecore-jss-nextjs npm package for each module version.
For example, for version 22.1.3 of sitecore-jss-nextjs package, the minimum compatible version of nextjs is 14.2.7: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs/v/22.1.3?activeTab=code

Currently, In my recent xm cloud project I am working with next.js with ^14.1.0 version.
Before that I was using next with ^13.4.16 version.
Also for @sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs before I was using with ~21.6.0 and now ~22.0.0.
I experienced that ^13.4.16 version is more stabled version then ^14.1.0 with sitecore JSS (for both version).
as in ^14.1.0, I have observed some points,

In local it is taking time to reload pages
After saving changes, changes are not directly reflecting manually. I have to refresh every-time when I change anything.


Although this is useful information about what I assume is Sitecore 10.4 (as you mention JSS 22), I am still looking from some kind of table that shows me the last supported version of Next for each version of Sitecore/JSS.
